# Stream uint8 through stdin/stdout in nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, buffer

I have two simple node scripts that I like to pipe together in bash. I want to stream 2 integers from one script to the other. Something goes wrong when moving to the next bit, e.g. 127 can be expressed in 7 bits while 128 needs 8 bits, if I understand correctly. My guess is that it has something tot do with the sign of the integer, e.g. plus or minus. I have specifically used `writeUInt8` and `readUInt8` for this reason though...

Script *in.js*, sends 2 integers to *stdout*:

```
process.stdout.setEncoding('binary');

const buff1 = Buffer.alloc(1);
const buff2 = Buffer.alloc(1);

buff1.writeUInt8(127);
buff2.writeUInt8(128);

process.stdout.write(buff1);
process.stdout.write(buff2);

process.stdout.end();
```

Script *out.js*, reads from *stdin* and writes to *stdout* again:

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('binary');
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    for(const uInt of data) {
        const v = Buffer.from(uInt).readUInt8();
        process.stdout.write(v + '\n');
    }
});
```

In bash I connect in and out:

```
$ node in.js | node out.js
```

Expected result:

```
127
128
```

Actual Result:

```
127
194
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the encoding to binary is messing the received data in *in.js*.

According to the [Readable Stream documentation of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding):

> By default, no encoding is assigned and stream data will be returned
>   as `Buffer` objects.

I tested the code below and it works:

```js
// in.js
process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    const v = data.readUInt8(i);
    process.stdout.write(v + '\n');
  }
});
```